# Disable Spell Check for People Picker - InfoPath Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Could you please help me in disabling the Spell Check for People Picker field in InfoPath Form ?

I came through few codes. But, that doesn't help me with the InfoPath form.

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('div').blur(function(){
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var HtmlPlaceHolder = document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2');

            var InputHtml = HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < InputHtml.length; i++)
            {
                InputHtml[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }

            var HtmlTextArea= HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (var i = 0; i < HtmlTextArea.length; i++)
            {
                HtmlTextArea[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }
        },2000);
    });

    $('input').blur(function(){
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var HtmlPlaceHolder = document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2');

            var InputHtml = HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < InputHtml.length; i++)
            {
            InputHtml[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }

            var HtmlTextArea= HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (var i = 0; i < HtmlTextArea.length; i++)
            {
            HtmlTextArea[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }
        },2000);
    });

        $('textarea').blur(function(){
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var HtmlPlaceHolder = document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2');

            var InputHtml = HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < InputHtml.length; i++)
            {
            InputHtml[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }

            var HtmlTextArea= HtmlPlaceHolder.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            for (var i = 0; i < HtmlTextArea.length; i++)
            {
            HtmlTextArea[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
            }
        },2000);
    });
```